# Replace any string between quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

**Problem:**

Cannot find a consistent way to replace a random string between quotes with a specific string I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Example:**

```
String str1 = "test=\"-1\"";
```

should become

```
String str2 = "test=\"31\"";
```

but also work for

```
String str3 = "test=\"foobar\"";
```

basically I want to turn this

```
String str4 = "test=\"antyhingCanGoHere\"";
```

into this

```
String str4 = "test=\"31\"";
```

**Have tried:**

[Case insensitive Regex without using RegexOptions enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439965/case-insensitive-regex-without-using-regexoptions-enumeration)

[How do you do case-insensitive string replacement using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139439/how-do-you-do-case-insensitive-string-replacement-using-regular-expressions)

[Replace any character in between AnyText: and <usernameredacted@example.com> with an empty string using Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530123/replace-any-character-in-between-anytext-and-usernameredactedexample-com-wit)

[Replace string in between occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564725/replace-string-in-between-occurrences)

[Replace a String between two Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403639/replace-a-string-between-two-strings)

**Current code:**

```
    Regex RemoveName = new Regex("(?VARIABLE=\").*(?=\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    String convertSeccons = RemoveName.Replace(ruleFixed, "31");
```

**Returns error:**

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
  Message=parsing "(?VARIABLE=").*(?=")" - Unrecognized grouping construct.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanGroupOpen()
       at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
       at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
       at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, Boolean useCache)
       at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options)
       at application.application.insertGroupID(String rule) in C:\Users\winserv8\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\application\application\MainFormLauncher.cs:line 298
       at application.application.xmlqueryDB(String xmlSaveLocation, TextWriter tw, String ruleName) in C:\Users\winserv8\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\application\application\MainFormLauncher.cs:line 250
  InnerException:
```

**found answer**

```
string s = Regex.Replace(ruleFixed, "VARIABLE=\"(.*)\"", "VARIABLE=\"31\"");
ruleFixed = s;
```

I found this code sample at Replace any character in between AnyText: and  with an empty string using Regex? which is one of the links i previously posted and just had skipped over this syntax because i thought it wouldnt handle what i needed.

Comment: what are the expected results.. can you clarify what you are wanting as an end result..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i just added more description to what i wanted. basically i want to turn this, String str4 = "test=\"antyhingCanGoHere\"";, into this, String str4 = "test=\"31\"";.

Comment: Have you tried naive RegExpr `\".*\"` ?

Comment: Can you clarify with a sample output for each input?

Comment: add that to your question..also remove all the links in your post that are irrelevant to your issue that you are having..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = Regex.Replace(ruleFixed, "VARIABLE=\"(.*)\"", "VARIABLE=\"31\"");
ruleFixed = s;
```

I found this code sample at [Replace any character in between AnyText: and <usernameredacted@example.com> with an empty string using Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530123/replace-any-character-in-between-anytext-and-usernameredactedexample-com-wit) which is one of the links i previously posted and just had skipped over this syntax because i thought it wouldnt handle what i needed.

Comment: This won't work correctly unless your `ruleFixed` string does not contain any other quote marks. Is that true? Please [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14224924/57611) for how to stop matching when the value inside the quotes ends.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str1 = "test=\"foobar\"";
var str2 = str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf("\"") + 1) + "31\"";
```

If needed add check for `IndexOf` != -1

Comment: This doesn't meet his use case of searching for a particular value.

Comment: @ErikE He does not want to search for a particular value but rather replace a random value inside the quotes

Comment: To clarify: this doesn't test for the format `test="foobar"`. It just finds any old `"foobar"`, even `donotchangethis="foobar"`. Plus, you're not replacing the contents of the original string but making a new one. The whole string he's replacing in can be many lines long! Not a matching scenario.

Comment: @ErikE I'd say `donotchangethis="foobar"` should be changed since the requirement is to set any value inside quotes. Also there is no such thing as "replacing" since strings are immutable.

Comment: I may have incorrectly believed there were other parts to the string beyond the single key/value pair. However, if you read the OP carefully (paying attention to his own solution presented) you will see that the requirement *is not* "any value inside quotes".

Comment: @ErikE I suppose you could be right, but without looking at his not working code, and reading the question; "replace a random string between quotes with a specific string I want", one could assume _that_ is what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you correct, but if you want to replace all chars inside `string`, why aren't you using simple regular expresission

```
String str = "test=\"-\"1\"";

Regex regExpr = new Regex("\".*\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
String result = regExpr.Replace(str , "\"31\"");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

prints:

```
test="31"
```

**Note:** You can take advantage of plain old `XAttribute`

```
String ruleFixed = "test=\"-\"1\"";

var splited = ruleFixed.Split('=');
var attribute = new XAttribute(splited[0], splited[1]);

attribute.Value = "31";

Console.WriteLine(attribute);//prints test="31"
```

Comment: That's going to be too greedy, I expect.  I'd suggest `[^"]*` instead.  But it might not be, depending on the actual usecases...

Comment: I know, I assume we need to be greedy, let me double-check. Well, he wrote `random string`. I will update to have two options

Comment: except escape the `"` in the capture group: `[^\"]*`

Comment: the full regex is `\"[^\"]*\"` which is essentially anything that is not a double quote that is between two double quotes

Comment: This doesn't test for the format `test="foobar"`. It just finds any old `"something"`, even `donotchangethis="foobar"`.

Comment: true.  the title from the OP just specifies between two quotes.  you can add a positive lookbehind to it: `(?<=test=)\"[^\"]*\"`

Comment: @Steve Is it normal answer questions based on title alone and not look at the explanation in the question text?

Comment: @ErikE definitely not!  However a response to an almost-correct comment on an actual answer is another matter :)

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure what you're saying. In any case my comment above was not about your comment, but about the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that your string has other things in it besides just the key/value pair of `key="value"`, then you need to make the value-match part *not* match quote marks, or it will match all the way from the first value to the last quote mark in the string.

If that is true, then try this:

```
Regex.Replace(ruleFixed, "(?<=VARIABLE\s*=\s*\")[^\"]*(?=\")", "31");
```

This uses negative look-behind to match the `VARIABLE="` part (with optional white space around it so `VARIABLE = "` would work as well, and negative look-ahead to match the ending `"`, without including the look-ahead/behind in the final match, enabling you to just replace the value you want.

If not, then your solution *will* work, but is not optimal because you have to repeat the value and the quote marks in the replace text.

Comment: what about a positive lookbehind (variable name and preceding double quote) and lookahead (trailing double quote): `(?<=test\s*=\s*\")[^\"]*(?=\")`  That way you could just make the replacement with the new value, rather than the whole string.

Comment: You could also use ? - If you try to match .*? that will perform a non-greedy pattern match which won't include the closing quote

Comment: @Steve I think that would be a superior answer, to replace only the part needing replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts = given.Split('=');
return string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", parts[0], replacement);
```

Comment: And if it starts with `wrongkey="value"` you've incorrectly replaced it rather than only paying attention to `rightkey="value"`.

Comment: @ErikE:  That assumes `given` was incorrectly found and not something this function would care about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string within the quotes does not contain quotes itself, you can use this general pattern in order to find a position between a prefix and a suffix:

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

In your case

```
(?<=\w+=").*?(?=")
```

Here we are using the prefix `\w+="` where `\w+` denotes word characters (the variable) and `="` are the equal sign and the quote.

We want to find anything `.*?` until we encounter the next quote.

The suffix is simply the quote `"`.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=\\w+=\").*?(?=\")", replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^"\r\n]*(?:""[\r\n]*)*
```

Comment: I was thinking that way, too, based on the title, but the desire is only for quoted strings in the form `test="value"`, not just any old `"value"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String str1 = "test=\"-1\"";
     string res = Regex.Replace(str1, "(^+\").+(\"+)", "$1" + "31" + "$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = "\"(.*)?\"";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var replacement = regex.Replace("test=\"hereissomething\"", "\"31\"");
```

Comment: This will not work.. it returns "test=\"31\"" he wants the ending \"" to be removed to `yield "test=\"31\`

Comment: No he doesn't - unless I've completely misunderstood the question it looks as though he wants to replace strings that are between opening and closing quotes - both sets of quotes are present in the all examples in the question

Comment: @levelnis He only wants strings that are introduced by a particular value as in `key1="whatever"`. He doesn't want to match `key2="whatever"`.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I think you're misunderstanding the requirements.

Comment: @levelins you could be right, and my apologies if so. I may have incorrectly believed that the input string had other values in it besides this one.

Comment: I am not looking at this question I think the OP is confused on what he / she wants

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "test=\"-1\"";
string[] parts = str1.Split(new[] {'"'}, 3);
string str2 = parts.Length == 3 ? string.Join(@"\", parts.First(), "31", parts.Last()) : str1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty bad at `RegEx` but you could make a simple `ExtensionMethod` using string functions to do this.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceBetweenQuotes(this string str, string replacement)
    {
        if (str.Count(c => c.Equals('"')) == 2)
        {
            int start = str.IndexOf('"') + 1;
            str = str.Replace(str.Substring(start, str.LastIndexOf('"') - start), replacement);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 String str3 = "test=\"foobar\"";
 str3 = str3.ReplaceBetweenQuotes("31");

returns: "test=\"31\""
```